# Labels for Keras Model Predicting Multi-Classification Problem

Tags: python, keras, label, predict

If I have a set of targets a.k.a y's as `[1,0,9,9,7,5,4,0,4,1]` and I use `model.predict(X)` Keras returns a 6 item array for each of the 10 samples. It returns 6 items because there are 6 possible targets (0,1,4,5,7,9) and keras returns a decimal/float (for each label) representing likelihood of any one of those being the correct target. For the first sample, for example - where y=1 Keras returns an array that looks like this: `[.1, .4,.003,.001,.5,.003]`.

I want to know which value matches to which target (does .1 refer to 1 because it's first in the dataset or 0 because it's the lowest number or 9 because it's the last number, etc). **How does Keras order it's predictions?** [The documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) does not seem to articulate this; it only says

> "Generates output predictions for the input samples."

So I'm not sure how to match the labels to the prediction results.

EDIT:

Here is my model and training code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

Y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
Y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
x = MaxPooling1D(4)(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(4)(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(4)(x)  # global max pooling
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(labels_Index, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras doesn't order anything, it all depend on how the classes in the data you used to train the model are defined and one-hot encoded.

You can usually recover the integer class label by taking the `argmax` of the class probability array for each sample.

From your example, 0.1 is class 0, 0.4 is class 1, 0.003 is class 2, 0.001 is class 3, 0.5 is class 4, and 0.003 is class 5 (6 classes in total).

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this! I don't want to find the integer class label (for this question). I want to find what the integer class label *that ties* to my labels. All Keras knows is the data I trained it on. Imagine I didn't even encode - and that these (0,1,4,5,7,9) are just discrete integers that identify my classes. (0,1,2,3,4,5) are the very same classes but are meaningless to me because I don't know which one of my labels tie to them.

Comment: Keras does not store that information, the semantic meaning of thr labels is something defined at model training and has to be saved separately.

Comment: How? That might be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @LiamHanninen You should include the training script in your question for that to be answerable.

Comment: @LiamHanninen I don't see the dataset or the labels, the semantic meaning comes from the dataset.